# Where should we use phrase "wouldn't be a shabby"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning

I have heard multiple times that one says something and end it with "wouldn't be a shabby".

Can you explain what does this exactly mean? Is it common and OK to use this in daily conversations?(U.S.A)

Comment: At least in my region of the USA I've never heard that.  Or I might just be too old.  Or too young.

Comment: I've never heard it anywhere in the US.  Can you find an example?  Is it possible the person is saying "wouldn't be *too* shabby"?  For example, someone might say, "Living in the Bahamas?  That wouldn't be too shabby!"  Used that way, it's a kind of understatement that actually means "That would be a good thing."

Comment: Yes, "wouldn't be shabby" or wouldn't be too shabby" to indicate something desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *That* **wouldn't be shabby**
>   *That* **wouldn't be too shabby**

meaning "it would not be too bad", or "it could be worse" (it could be shabby).

> **That's not too shabby**. *( that's not bad at all )*

**Shabby** means *something* is in poor condition, usually through wear and tear.

There is specific fashion called [**shabby chic**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shabby_chic) where decorations are not new and pristine, but rather worn or distressed and possibly with a patina. Older looking house furnishings would also be part of the look (there is a shop in SoHo, NYC called Shabby Chic).  In some of its forms it could be considered to be the look of old money.

It should not be confused with **Xabi** (pronounced "*shabby*") which is a Spanish male name as in Xabi Alonso, the Bayern Munich centre midfielder.